# OpenMDAO - Dymos. Interpolate the results of a phase onto an equispaced grid

Tags: openmdao

I have the results of a phase in the output grid of my transcription. To perform some further analyses, I need to have my results in an equispaced grid. How can I use the resulting collocated polynomials to obtain the values of my timeseries outputs at the coordinates of the new equispaced grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be accomplished by using a second timeseries output:  https://openmdao.github.io/dymos/features/phases/timeseries.html#interpolated-timeseries-outputs

To do this, you're going to want the secondary timeseries to use a 3rd-order Gauss-Lobatto transcription.

- a 3rd Gauss-Lobatto segment consists of 3 nodes
- the value of each state is input at the two endpoints
- the value of each control is input at the two endpoints and the midpoint
- if left unspecified, the segments in the phase are equidistantly spaced
- if we use a "compressed" transcription, the state values at the common point of consecutive segments is only provided once

So, based on the test case [here](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/dymos/blob/master/dymos/examples/brachistochrone/test/test_tandem_phases.py#L71) you could do something like the following:

```
tx_2 = dm.GaussLobatto(num_segments=10, order=3, compressed=True)
phase.add_timeseries('timeseries2', transcription=tx_2, subset='state_input')
```

Dymos will perform the interpolation from the phase's primary transcription onto the discretization specified for `timeseries2`.